# SSRS Hide duplicate columns in tandem

Tags: duplicates, ssrs-2008

Data Example

```
**Row Location   Column Location  Other Location**
1.28              A                 02-120
1.28              A                 02-121
1.28              A                 02-211
1.28              B                 02-213
1.28              B                 02-320
1.28              B                 02-203
1.28              B                 02-201
1.28              C                 02-314
```

I want to duplicate hidden for Row and Column location except when either row or column location changes

EXAMPLE:

```
**Row Location         Column Location                Other Location**
1.28                  A                               02-120
                                                      02-121 
                                                      02-211
1.28                  B                               02-213
                                                      02-320
                                                      02-203
                                                      02-201
1.29                  B                               02-314
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup groups in your table object. There are lots of information if you google.

Below is an example. You need to group by Row Location and Column Location.

[image]

You will Notice Row Groups. To add group you need to right mouse click on Detail in Row Groups and a menu will pop up to add.

Once you added the Group you can right mouse click and get the properties to display (see below).
You will need to group by your Row Location and Column Location.

[image]